# Failed to run elasticsearch --version command

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

**Elasticsearch Version - 5.5.1, 
Java Version - 8-u131**

*When I run the elasticsearch version command(or elasticsearch-plugin install), instead of displaying the version it shows this stacktrace:*

```
>./elasticsearch --version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Configuration class specified
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:198)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureStatusLogger(LogConfigurator.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureWithoutConfig(LogConfigurator.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:170)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)V
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration.<init>(BuiltConfiguration.java:58)
    ... 12 more
```

This seems like a case of missing/incorrect versioning of log4j jars packaged with elasticsearch 5.5.1 rpm.

Answer (score 0):

It ships with 2.9.1 and missing method appeared in 2.7.x. Do you have the same exception with zip version? You might want to add `set -x` as second line in `elasticsearch` script file and check what is passed in `-cp "$ES_CLASSPATH"` - maybe it picks up some old jars from some other path.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 5.5.1 zip ships with 2.8.2 version of log4J jars. I verified with set -x, it is picking up all the jars from the lib directory. What is surprising me is this works on few machines and behaves as mentioned above on few other machines.